# Run a container on a pod failure Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a cronjob that runs and does things regularly. I want to send a slack message with the technosophos/slack-notify container when that cronjob fails.

Is it possible to have a container run when a pod fails?

Comment: Hey! I know this is a little late, but the slack-notify image was originally intended to be used with Brigade (checkout brigade.sh) - it does exactly what you are looking for, it allows you to create a pipeline of jobs on a Kubernetes cluster, and define that pipeline in JavaScript, so you can create a job, and if it fails, execute it - check out https://github.com/technosophos/slack-notify#in-brigade for an example specifically on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built in for this that i am aware of. You could use a web hook to get notified when a pod changes and look for state stuff in there. But you would have to build the plumbing yourself or look for an existing third party tool.

Answer (score 2):

Pods and Jobs are different things. If you want to wait for a job that has failed and send an email after it has, you can do something like this in bash:

```
while true
do
  kubectl wait --for=condition=failed job/myjob
  kubectl run --image=technosophos/slack-notify --env="EMAIL=failure@yourdomain.com"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

**To the question:  Is it possible to have a container run when a pod fails?**

Yes , although there is nothing out of the box right now , but you can define a health check.

Then you can write a cron job , or a Jenkins job , or a custom kubernetes cluster service/controller  that checks/probes that health check regularly and if the health check fails then you can run a container based on that.